# Building gtest on msys2 fails in install, similar problem on other packages

Tags: cmake, msys2

When trying to install google test on MSYS2, I use:

```
cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" ..
make
```

This works, the code is generated with no errors.  Then, to install:

```
make install
```

This unfortunately, does not work.  There seems to be a common problem, other packages have similar issues.

```
-- Installing: C:/Program Files/googletest-distribution/include
CMake Error at googlemock/cmake_install.cmake:31 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot make directory "C:/Program
  Files/googletest-distribution/include": No such file or directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:32 (include)
```

Is this a permissions problem? I tried sudo, but that does not exist on msys2.

The line number 31 of the error seems wrong, that's a comment:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY)
  # Include the install script for each subdirectory.
  include("D:/git/extcode/googletest/build/googlemock/cmake_install.cmake")

endif()
```

line 32 is the include, which refers to d:,not c:, so I do not understand the message being generated?

Comment: As usual, for installing under "C:/Program Files" you need administrator capabilities. The error occures at `googlemock/cmake_install.cmake:31`; the line at `cmake_install.cmake:32` is just the next step in the call stack (a command `include()` reads the file, passed to it, and executes all commands in that file).

Comment: so how do you do it under msys2? sudo does not exist.  Wouldn't it be better to install in /d/msys64/  or under /mingw64 rather than the windows system?